# Reference to this is not accessible inside traditional function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using Angular 9 for web development. I wanted to implement typeahead feature in my application. So I am using ng bootstrap typeahead. everything works perfectly as mentioned into below code.

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(150),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term =>
        this.GameService.getCode(term).pipe(
          catchError(() => {
            return of([]);
          }))
      ),
    )
```

but somehow this is not working into the IE browser as it does not have support for arrow functions. To resolve this probem i have modified code in below manner:

```
search = function(text$: Observable<string>) {
    return text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(150),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term => {
        let self = this;  // this is undefined and hence self is also undefined
        return self.GameService.getCode(term).pipe(
          map((res) => {
            this.isSearching = false;
            return res;
          }),
          catchError(() => {
            return of([]);
          }))
      }
      ),
    )
  }
```

how do i customize this code to support IE browser.

Comment: Why not just use a transpiler?

Comment: Notice that the `const self = this` needs to go *outside* of the `function`. Also your second snippet is still using arrow functions, and has an additional `map()` call that's not there in your original code.

Comment: could you please elaborate more on this

Answer (score 2):

Try defining `let self = this` before entering the `function`.

When using a function expression you you lose the scope of your code and your access to `this` - so you want to save your `this` before you enter your first `function`.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: You still have some arrow functions in your second code snippet - at `switchMap()`, `map()` and `catchError()`

Comment: tried replacing switchMap also with traditional function declaration but still no success

Comment: It's unclear to me if you've replaced all arrow functions or just the `switchMap()` one.

Comment: I have tried replacing all arrow functions

Comment: Can you please post the current code and error you're getting?

Comment: `search = function (text$: Observable<string>) {

    console.log(text$);
    let self = this;
    return text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(150),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(function (term) {
        return self.GameService.getCode(term).pipe(
          map(function (res) {
            this.isSearching = false;
            return res;
          }),
        )
      }
      ),
    )
  }`

Error: 

`Property GameService` does not exist on type window & typeof globalThis